# Mysql compare two tables and display unmatch

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables:

**test1**

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
| 1  | john | 23  |
| 2  | jane | 22  |
+----+------+-----+
```

**test2**

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
+----+------+-----+
| 1  | john | 23  |
| 2  | jane | 21  |
+----+------+-----+
```

I want to display only `id` number 2 because the age did not match from table `test1`

**Sample Output:**

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | age |
| 2  | jane | 21  |
+----+------+-----+
```

This is my current attempt at a query:

```
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE age NOT IN (SELECT age FROM test2)
```

Comment: Do you want to compare all columns from table 1 to table 2, display only records having any value is mismatch?

Comment: Yes, @IndraPrakashTiwari, is there a way to display also the table name were in the mismatch came from?

Comment: you can do in two ways, 1. must be provide all columns in where clause with or operator... e.g. ... table1.col1<>table2.col1 or table1.col2<>table2.col2 or .... etc. or you must write dynamic query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN, This may help you.

```
SELECT test1.* FROM test1 INNER JOIN test2 ON test1.name = test2.name 
AND test1.age <> test2.age
```

Working [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/becba/1) for your reference

Comment: Hi @Nilesh can you show what table the mismatch came from?

Comment: its test1 table, if you wish to have it from test2 then just change your query to `SELECT test2.* FROM....`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM test1 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test2 WHERE age <> t.age)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the results you want

```
SELECT test1.id as id1, test2.id as id2, test1.name, test1.age as age1, test2.age as age2
FROM test1,test2
WHERE test1.name = test2.name 
AND test1.age != test2.age
```